# LDAP authentication in JAVA web application

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to authenticate userid and password of user from LDAP here is my java code

```
Hashtable<Object, String> props = new Hashtable<Object, String>();
//props.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,
        "uid=muhammad.zafar,ou=IT Operations,ou=Information Systems,dc=bi,dc=com,dc=pk");  
props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "Passw0rd");
DirContext context;

try {

    context = com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance("ldap://ldap.bi.com.pk:389/dc=bi,dc=com,dc=pk" + '/', props);
    context.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid Username or Password");
}
```

it works great as user muhammad.zafar exists in IT Operation "ou". But I don't want to validate user with its ou so I tried many settings for SECURITY_PRINCIPAL and none of them worked for me

```
props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,
                "uid=muhammad.zafar");
```

it throws the exception "javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]"
even I tried to put in

```
props.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
```

none of them worked for me. I hope my question is clear as I don't have every user "ou" within my application.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution, hope it works for you 
[possible solution](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24630660/Java-Active-Directory-Which-groups-does-a-user-belong-to.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a question of whether you want to authenticate with the `ou` or without it.

The fact is that the LDAP protocol and JNDI in `simple` authentication mode (See [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ldap/simple.html)) require you to put as `SECURITY_PRINCIPAL` the dn of the user.

So you have 2 ways to deal with that :

- Use a technical account to search for the DN of the user which tries to authenticate and after that do the authentication with the dn previously found
- Do not use `simple` authentication mechanism, but a SASL one supported by your Directory which allows you to use other value than the dn.

  See this for more informations : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ldap/sasl.html

Comment: can please provide example for this "Do not use simple authentication mechanism, but a SASL one supported by your Directory which allows you to use other value than the dn."

Comment: @Jahangeer The documentation I posted has links to examples with authentication based on Digest, Kerberos, CRAM MD5, etc.